# How to increase the root partition in embedded Linux with fdisk and resize2fs when root partition is in between two important partition

Tags: partition, root

I am using DE0-Nano-SoC / Atlas board. The connection to this board is through the Putty running in host computer.I have a problem to increase the root partition.

```
root@socfpga:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7744 MB, 7744782336 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 236352 cylinders, total 15126528 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd68e23ba

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1         2121728     3799447      838860    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/mmcblk0p2           14336     2111487     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p3            2048        4095        1024   a2  Unknown
/dev/mmcblk0p4         3799448    15126527     5663540    5  Extended
/dev/mmcblk0p5         3801496    15126527     5662516   83  Linux
```

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

```
root@socfpga:~# df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root               975.9M    221.1M    703.6M  24% /
devtmpfs                246.9M      4.0K    246.9M   0% /dev
tmpfs                   503.0M     52.0K    503.0M   0% /var/volatile
tmpfs                   503.0M         0    503.0M   0% /media/ram
```

Currently defined functions:

```
    [, [[, ar, ash, awk, basename, bunzip2, bzcat, cat, chattr, chgrp,
    chmod, chown, chroot, chvt, clear, cmp, cp, cpio, cut, date, dc, dd,
    deallocvt, df, diff, dirname, dmesg, dnsdomainname, dpkg-deb, du,
    dumpkmap, dumpleases, echo, egrep, env, expr, false, fbset, fdisk,
    fgrep, find, flock, free, fsck, fsck.minix, fuser, grep, groups,
    gunzip, gzip, halt, head, hexdump, hostname, hwclock, id, ifconfig,
    ifdown, ifup, insmod, ip, kill, killall, klogd, less, ln, loadfont,
    loadkmap, logger, logname, logread, losetup, ls, lsmod, md5sum,
    microcom, mkdir, mkfifo, mkfs.minix, mknod, mkswap, mktemp, modprobe,
    more, mount, mv, nc, netstat, nohup, nslookup, od, openvt, patch,
    pidof, ping, ping6, pivot_root, poweroff, printf, ps, pwd, rdate,
    readlink, realpath, reboot, renice, reset, rm, rmdir, rmmod, route,
    run-parts, sed, seq, setconsole, sh, sleep, sort, start-stop-daemon,
    strings, stty, swapoff, swapon, switch_root, sync, sysctl, syslogd,
    tail, tar, tee, telnet, test, tftp, time, top, touch, tr, traceroute,
    true, tty, udhcpc, udhcpd, umount, uname, uniq, unzip, uptime, users,
    usleep, vi, watch, wc, wget, which, who, whoami, xargs, yes, zcat
```

I want to increase the size of `/dev/mmcblk0p2`

Tried two methods:

1. This partition p2 is between partition p1 ans p3, command `resize2fs` corrupts working image
2. Partition table entry are not in order. `fdisk` with 't' option to correct this also corrupt the working image. I can't go beyond this.